# Active Active failover

Tags: load-balancing, lvs

I have an application which is handling UDP traffic. Need to run the setup in active-active mode with two machines and only one IP exposed to external world.

Will LVS be helpful in this scenario or any other tools available for the same ?

Comment: Your question has made me consider the idea, that despite LVS being around for many years, I don't know anyone recently using it, or deploying it for production services. (this is typically "a bad sign") However I've not heard of anyone using it, and saying "it didnt' work for reason X, Y and Z. So I would be interested if you make a pilot project that you could report back any findings.

Comment: The short answer is yes. LVS works good for this type of application. You should however always look around for alternatives to get an understand of what is out there.

Answer (score 0):

To run in active-active mode with a single IP address, you will need to implement either

1. A load balancer to distribute the requests to your 2 active nodes, or
2. To use a native "virtual ip address" network based load balancing such as [NLB from microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742455.aspx), or a [CARP type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Address_Redundancy_Protocol) implementation.

Fortunately the decision is pretty easy, because NLB and similar technologies such as [LVS can](http://kb.linuxvirtualserver.org/wiki/ARP_Issues_in_LVS/DR_and_LVS/TUN_Clusters) be  [pretty poor](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/suck_donkey_balls), and [don't](http://communities.cisco.com/thread/21313) play [well](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/278431).

Regarding whether LVS is appropriate depends on your requirements, hence you probably need to provide details of the service and application. But there are a list of design examples for deployments using LVS here, one of which might suit your need;
http://kb.linuxvirtualserver.org/wiki/Examples